Can EmailJS turn a submission form into a pdf before it sends? Fill in a couple fields and hit send instead of plain text it emails as PDF
I had someone ask me if it is possible to send the submission form as a PDF instead of a standard email. They want the attachment to come through with the questions and answers to show in the PDF and ready to print right away instead of having to print the email to PDF.
I have not been able to find any support on this in EmailJS docs. The only thing I have seen is how to add attachments and when I search else where I have not seen this question asked at all.
